# How to extract browser login credentials from memory dump?

Tags: passwords, web-browser, forensics, memory

Does anyone know if there is a way to extract passwords for social networks like from a browser memory dump? [I tried this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gl32HES2gwQ) without success.

I used dumpit.exe tool to make a full dump of the system after I logged in to Gmail and Facebook, then I opened the .dmp file with HxD.exe (a hex viewer). I searched for the words `passwd`, `password`, `pass=` and my password, but I can't find any

then  i try to use this commnads to search in strings and i search for my password also i cant find any

> strings DESKTOP-HIAD61E-20181022-081417.dmp | grep password > g.txt
>
> strings DESKTOP-HIAD61E-20181022-081417.dmp | grep passwd > h.txt

Does anyone have any idea how I can do that?

Comment: It is always very important that you explain all your steps and what you tried. We should not have to ask what you did. In answer to your question, use the steps laid out in the tutorial and make sure that you set up your computer using any steps explained in the video. As for why your attempts are not working, we cannot know.

Comment: okay i will explain more